# How to select specific values from a list of array in Loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have a scenario where I need to remove a product from a list of products under that batch using Loadrunner.

In first transaction after login we need to select a batch from list of batches available in that store. For Example we select a batch called "A102" and under that batch we have 4 products. I have selected a product and removed it. For each Product we have few values called Specification Id, Serial No. and tag Id.

Suppose the four products are Tv, Fridge, Oven and speaker.
For 2 products we have tag id's mentioned as 71234 and 71567 respectively, but for other 2 we dont tag Id's and showing as NA in UI. I have selected a product with tag Id and correlated all the dynamic values for Specification Id, Serial No. and tag Id. But as we dont have tag Id's for 2 products we are not getting 2 tag Id's in response.

So if we correlate values for 4 products
we are getting 4 Specification Id's
4 Serial No,s
2 Tag Id's
So how to select a product which is having all the three values and starting with 71 only.
How to do this in Loadrunner.

Comment: Why C & Java tags? I do not see any code in any of those languages. Removed. Do not use unrelated tags as it is spam. I don't see any performance testing here  too

Comment: we need to write code to make it work.

Comment: where is this code? "We"? You need to write it - we can answer specific questions related to the code you posted.

Comment: Great Interview question